# Position text vertically central inside absolutely positioned div without using pixel units

Tags: html, css, css-position, viewport

I am looking for a way to position the `<h1>` tag below vertically central inside the absolutely positioned container div. I am aware of `display: table` and `display: table-cell`, however this does not play well with absolute positioning.

```
<div class="position--relative">
    <div class="position--absolute">
        <h1>POSITION THIS TEXT CENTRALLY INSIDE THE CONTAINER</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way I can position this text centrally *without* using `px` units? This is because it will need to stay central on various viewports.

Comment: There are many other units besides PX, since you ask about viewport height -> try **vh**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong with `display: table` and `display: table-cell`

Try this:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.position--relative {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.position--absolute {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="position--relative">
  <div class="position--absolute">
    <div class='table'>
      <div class='cell'>
        <h1>POSITION THIS TEXT CENTRALLY INSIDE THE CONTAINER</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/pjbm3w6n/1/)

Comment: Thanks, but I needed a `right: 0; top: 0;` on the absolutely positioned div to get this working.

Comment: Provide a case where provided snippet will fail...

Answer (score 0):

Move the element 50 % from top and than use a transform to move it up half of its size:

```
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  top: 50%;
}
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/67nfgmwf/)

Answer (score 0):

Using `transform` you can easily achieve this both horizontally and vertically.

```
 .position--absolute
 {
   position:absolute;  
   top:50%;
   left:50%;
   transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/fe0t3by2/7/)

Nice article available with so many scenario's. https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 0):

Here you go if you don't want to use `table` and `table-cell` :) `top` and `left` set to `50%`. The `translate` value for `transform` is based off the size of the element, so that will center nicely.

**Read more about these tricks in** - https://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/
**Snippet**

```css
.position--relative {
  position: relative;
  height: 250px;
  background: #333;
}
.position--absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
h1 {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="position--relative">
  <div class="position--absolute">
    <h1>POSITION THIS TEXT CENTRALLY INSIDE THE CONTAINER</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```